# Capitalization: "Our Planet"

Tags: capitalization

In the following sentence, "Science has made navigation to all parts of our planet possible," what are the capitalization rules for the words *our planet?*

> our Planet
>
> Our Planet

Comment: I think this question is a bit too basic for Our Website

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Have you visited our site for English Language Learners? You can find it [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). It's great for basic questions. :-)

Comment: '@FumbleFingers:  I am not sure I agree.  I remember when our planet was called the earth and now Earth is partially covered with earth. . . . . Or something like that. As I was asking Dad just last night, "Why, in the name of Our Father, is my father not celebrating Earth Day?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not capitalize random words in the middle of a sentence. That includes *our* and *planet*. The sentence is fine as stated. The sentence would not be fine otherwise.